# Enable keys in Azure AD application

Tags: azure-active-directory

I've created a App Registration in Azure AD however, the "Keys" option in the Settings blade is not displayed.  Based on all the articles I've read, this option should be available but for some reason it is not.  How do I make this option available?
[[the screenshot ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bl94.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bl94.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of application you registered is a **Native** application .Native applications are public clients in OAuth2 parlance. Those apps are meant to run on a device and aren't trusted to maintain a secret . So no keys property in Native application .

You should create a **Web app/API** application for your purpose. That is how you can create a confidential client which has both ID and Secret.

Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications) for more details .